# UnknownHostException using java.net.Socket

Tags: android, exception

I have this class

```
class ClientSocketClass {
    //connect to IP address 74.125.224.72, TCP port 80
    public static java.net.Socket connect1() {
        return(new java.net.Socket("74.125.224.72", 80));
    }

    //connect to www.google.com, TCP port 80
    public static java.net.Socket connect2() {
        return(new java.net.Socket("www.google.com", 80));
    }
}
```

I have this error

```
error: unreported exception UnknownHostException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    [javac] return(new java.net.Socket("www.google.com", 80));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log says it all. Try changing

```
public static java.net.Socket connect2() {
    return (new java.net.Socket("www.google.com", 80));
}
```

To this:

```
public static java.net.Socket connect2() throws UnknownHostException {
    return (new java.net.Socket("www.google.com", 80));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! do i need to import for the UnknownHost Exception?

Comment: Yes you do need to import any other classes that you use

Comment: Can you mark the answer as correct, if this solved your problem

Comment: one more thing, I'm planning to change it to asyntask... but I'm confused with how asynctask works... how do i move the socket from client socket class to MyTask class(this is my asynctask file).